# Elements in random array

Tags: php

I created a function for getting the limited random elements in array each time. i have tried everything to get this work. so the array is like this 
Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6 after limit of 4 i am getting Q2,Q4,Q6,Q3 then Q6,Q3,Q2,Q4 and so on but i am not getting Q1 and Q5 in any set. it just creates random elements out one time and shuffled around it.. 
So the main reason is i am stick to the some plugin code and i can't change any more functions otherwise it will break so is there a way to stick in this and change.

Thanks

There are two seperate conditions. so please don't confuse. i cant put down the whole code here .if you need to see i have putted down the gist link below

This condition is for updating the questions for next retake

```
if ( $quiz && $questions = $quiz->get_questions() ) {
$questions = array_values( array_intersect_key( $questions, array_flip( array_rand( $questions, 4 ) ) ) ) ;
shuffle( $questions );
$question_id = reset( $questions );
```

This condition randomize the questions

```
if {    
$question_ids = array_values( array_intersect_key( $quiz_questions, array_flip( array_rand( $quiz_questions, 4 ) ) ) ) ;

    shuffle( $question_ids );
    $random_quiz[ $quiz_id ] = $question_ids;
    $questions               = array();
        foreach ( $question_ids as $id ) {
        $questions[ $id ] = $quiz_questions[ $id ];

            }
      }
     return $questions;
```

https://gist.github.com/talha6248/acabd83e4da44d5a2a262d690db58dd1

Comment: Why not just `shuffle($questions); $questions = array_slice($questions, 0, 4);` ?

Comment: yes i also tried it still not show the 2 elements and shuffle around the same 4

Comment: It sounds like you might be removing the other two questions from the array somewhere? It works fine on [rextester](http://rextester.com/IOJW31943)

Comment: Yes if you be so kind to look at the gist code what i am doing wrong . Thanks